# Rate limiting requests from single IP by delay

Tags: haproxy

Does anybody know a way of using HAProxy to add incoming requests to a delay once a certain maximum number of requests reached and not just reject or send a status code, actually queue a specific IP address' requests and if not too many, allow once the number has reduced enough.

Using the documentation all the above parts seem possible independently although combined seems to be a problem.

I have the following in my front end:

```
#Add counter to ip in ratelimiting table
tcp-request content track-sc0 src table ratelimiting

# if alot of requests (more than 1000) - reject
acl mark_alot_of_requests sc0_conn_rate(ratelimiting) gt 1000
tcp-request content reject if mark_alot_of_requests TRUE

#If concurrent requests >= 100 from a single IP return 429
acl mark_too_many_requests sc0_conn_cur(ratelimiting) ge 100
use_backend 429_slow_down if mark_too_many_requests
```

Then

```
backend 429_slow_down
    mode http
    timeout tarpit 5s
    reqitarpit .
    errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/429.http
    http-request tarpit
```

Is my tarpit that i though did slow them down but doesn't behave in the way I initially thought.

The ratelimiting table is created in the listen as follows:

```
listen ratelimiting
    mode http
    stick-table type ip size 1m expire 1h store conn_rate(5000),conn_cur
```

Many thanks

Comment: What have you tried?  There are many articles that talk about using stick-tables to limit request rate by IP and/or by error count and many other fascets of the requests/responses.

Comment: Sorry, let me just update with my code